# Java class to allow multiple threads to read or one to modify at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Let's say you have the following class:

```
class A {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo getFoo() {
        return foo; //foo.clone()?
    }
    void modifyFoo() {
        //modify this.foo
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to allow:

- either multiple threads to call `getFoo()`
- or one thread to call `modifyFoo()`,
- once a thread wants to modify foo, no other new `getFoo()` calls arriving after that may be executed, until modification is done.

Are there classes already for this problem in Java or do I have to implement it? If I have to implement it, then how do I implement it ensure thread safety?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a Read-Write lock, fortunately, java provides one, `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. You can use it as follows:

```
class A {
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo getFoo() {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            Foo tmp = foo; //foo.clone()?
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    void modifyFoo() {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            //modify this.foo
            //...
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow any number of threads to call `getFoo()` simultaneously, but only one to call `modifyFoo()`. When modify foo is called, the thread will block until all read locks are released, then begin executing and prevent any new read locks from being acquired until it has finished. There are still concurrency issues to consider since the returned `Foo` can  be modified by the code that calls `getFoo`, but this should provide the basic tool you need.

Comment: You put `foo.clone()` as a comment, but I think it's necessary.  The code that gets Foo will probably then access its fields and those might be read in an inconsistent state if modifyFoo is called in another thread.  And the lock is of no help here.

Comment: That is true if you want to guarantee that it will be in a consistent state, however I simply wanted to demonstrate the necessary locking mechanism with as few alterations to the code as possible. There are situations in which the code as written could be correct however, if, for example, `foo` is never modified in place, but only ever assigned an entirely new value. In the general case, though, yes, cloning foo would be a safer option.

Comment: Agreed.  I know you did mention there are other concurrency issues to consider.  I wanted to make clear to @SolidSun that there is a lot to think about (very carefully) when dealing with concurrency.

Comment: Note: it is **extremelly bad practice** not to use a `finally` block surrounding a call to `unlock()`. You can easily blow up all your system without it. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Definitely so, sorry for the oversight, and thank you for the edit

Answer (score 4):

You should use a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Multiple threads can read, one thread can write which blocks all reads.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
    private volatile Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo getFoo() {
        return foo; //foo.clone()?
    }
    void synchronized modifyFoo() {
        //modify this.foo
        //...
    }
}
```

The `synchronized` keyword ensures that `modifyFoo()` is atomic, that is, won't allow multiple threads to invoke it at once.
The `volatile` keyword ensures that reads to `foo` do not return a cached version (which could have been outdated if another thread modified it) and instead returns the current, correct value.

Comment: It gets tricky here though. Despite having `Foo foo` being volatile, it doesn't ensure that all fields of Foo are volatile.  That means foo.getField() may return stale data (of whatever is returned from getField()) despite it being set in `modifyFoo`.  I would recommend having both methods being synchronized

Comment: @JohnVint - but even that doesn't save you if the `Foo` class isn't also protected by synchronization as after two threads call `getFoo()` they each have a reference and can step on each other.

Comment: I know about the `synchronized` keyword, but what if `getFoo()` isn't atomic either, but it makes no modification, and it is permissible to allow multiple threads to call `getFoo()` at the same time if no thread is calling `modifyFoo()`?

Comment: @Brian Roach good point. I guess my point was more of the loss of the happens-before relationship between invoking modifyFoo() and invoking getFoo(). But you are right, this example is only as thread-safe as Foo is.

Comment: @SolidSun The reason Brian Roach's comment is valid is because, when one thread is holding a reference to `Foo foo` and another thread enters the `synchronized` block the first thread can continue to invoke the `Foo`'s methods.  And if the other thread writes to A.foo, the first thread may see stale data.

Comment: As a result `Foo foo` also needs to worry about thread safety for memory visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get by with a **synchronized block.**

```
class A {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    void modifyFoo() {
        synchronized(foo){
            /* do your modify stuff */
        }
    }
}
```